# "I see only [a/one] spelling mistake" - which one to use?

Tags: meaning

Consider this below clause(or whatever it is called)

> This is correct grammer.

My friend and I are having an argument about the correctness of the below two sentences which refer to the above clause.

> 1. I see only a spelling mistake.
> 2. I see only one spelling mistake.

She says both are correct, but I feel only the second one is correct.
Who is right?

Edit: Is a spelling mistake also a grammatical mistake?

Comment: They are both valid sentences.  Whether they are correct or not depends on what each speaker sees and doesn't see.

Comment: Please never just ask “Which is correct?”  It shows no effort on your part, and gives us nothing to go on.  As [the Help Center says in its “How to ask a good question” section](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask):  **“Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!”** Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in my opinion, the first statement suggests that there could be another mistake in something that is not spelling like, for example, a grammatical mistake. The second statement suggests that the person reading can only see one spelling mistake, not two or three, and gives no suggestion of any other mistakes. 
So, they are both correct, but differ in meaning.